# Different variable output from same method JAVA genetic algorithm

Tags: java, oop, artificial-intelligence, genetic-algorithm

So i am trying to build a genetic algorithm on java i stuck on getting
fitness of my population here 3 classes from my project:

### Class Individu

```
public class Individu {

int Popsize=4;
int Health[]= new int[Popsize];   
int Attack[]= new int[Popsize];
int Atspeed[]= new int[Popsize];    
int Move[]= new int[Popsize];

int health,attack,lifetime,dmgdone,attspeed,range,move;
double fitness;
double Pitness[]= new double[20];
    
Random random = new Random();

public int setHealth(){
   
health = random.nextInt(150 - 75) + 75;
    
return health;
}
public int setAttack(){
attack = random.nextInt(10 - 5) + 10;
    
return attack;
}
public int setAttspeed(){
attspeed = random.nextInt(3 - 1) + 3;
    
return attspeed;
}
public int setMoveSpeed(){
move = random.nextInt(8 - 4) + 1;
    
return move;
}
      
public int getGeneHealth(int index) {
          
return Health[index];
}
public int getGeneAttack(int index) {
          
return Attack[index];
}
public int getGeneAtspedd(int index) {
          
return Atspeed[index];
}
public int getGeneMove(int index) {
          
return Move[index];
}

public void setGene(int index, int value) {
Health[index]=value;
Attack[index]=value;
Atspeed[index]=value;
Move[index]=value;
    
fitness = 0;
}
public int size() {
return Popsize;
}
      

      
public double[] GenerateIndividual(){
for (int i = 0; i <Popsize; i++) {
Health[i]=setHealth();
Attack[i]=setAttack();
Atspeed[i]=setAttspeed();
Move[i]=setMoveSpeed();
       

}
return Pitness;   
}
```

---

### Class Fitness

```
 public class Fitness {
 Individu individu= new Individu();

 double fitness;
 double Pitness[]= new double[20];
 public double getFitness(){
 individu.GenerateIndividual();
 for (int i = 0; i <=3; i++) {
 fitness=
 individu.getGeneHealth(i)+individu.getGeneAtspedd(i)+
 individu.getGeneAttack(i)+
 individu.getGeneMove(i));
 fitness=fitness/171;
 Pitness[i]=fitness;
 System.out.println("Health from class
 fitness"+individu.Health[i]);
 }
 return fitness;
 }

 }
```

## Main Class

```
public class main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
Individu aaa=new Individu();
Fitness bbb= new Fitness();
bbb.getFitness();
aaa.GenerateIndividual();
    


DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat();
df.setMaximumFractionDigits(3);

for (int i=0; i<=3; i++){
//System.out.println("Fitness         ");
System.out.println("Generasi ke         :"+i+1);
System.out.println("Health          "+aaa.getGeneHealth(i));
System.out.println("Attackspeed     "+aaa.getGeneAtspedd(i));
System.out.println("Attack          "+aaa.getGeneAttack(i));
System.out.println("movementSpeed   "+aaa.getGeneMove(i));
}     
}
}
```

What i struggle is when i run this script i got 2 double value from 1 variable first value is from Fitness class as i printed here

```
 System.out.println("Health from class fitness"+individu.Health[i]);
```

and second variable i printed here from Main Class

```
 System.out.println("Health "+aaa.getGeneHealth(i));
```

that 2 variable is always have different value causing my fitness and my generation is not correlated each other.
My question is how to make this 2 variable print same value?

Answer (score 0):

Well, aside from the many problems I can detect about the essentials of Genetic Algorithms, I see 'individu' and 'aaa' are two different Java objects.

```
Individu aaa=new Individu();
aaa.GenerateIndividual();
```

and

```
Individu individu= new Individu();
individu.GenerateIndividual();
```

Since your Health and Fitness are randomly generated on GenerateIndividual(), both 'aaa' and 'individu' will get different Health values.

I strongly recommend you to review GA essentials, since I can see many conception errors in your system.

Comment: I realize my coding was messy but i want built this code from scratch since i am newbie, is there any recommendation how to make them printed as 1 value while i print in 2 different classes?
thanks for your response

Comment: Use only one variable. Either aaa or individu

Comment: Was the suggestion helpful?